# If I don't know if a variable is positive/negative, how do I make it positive without calling a function or using if?

Tags: java, variables

This is the code (Java):

```
    float yd = waypointY - currentY;
    if (yd < 0) {
        yd = yd*(-1);
    }
```

I don't think this is the best way to do it, and have searched but only found results for when you already know if it's positive or negative. I never know if waypointY is more or less than currentY.

Comment: In most languages `if` is not a function. What you have is a pretty common pattern. i wouldn't be too worried about it. I might change it to `yd *= -1;` if my language supported it.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `java`, there is an `API` you can use, `Math.abs(x-y)` it will return the **absolute value** of `x-y` and the *source code of abs API as below:*

```
public static float abs(float a) {
    return (a <= 0.0F) ? 0.0F - a : a;
}
```

Comment: But this means calling a function, which essentially is no more effective than a simple if-statement. Correct? (I'm unsure)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is impossible without if. Or some variation of. Maybe get the sign bit and multiply by something and add something and do something? This seems way too complex, any particular reason not to use if?

Edit:
you could use a ternary (or whatever it's called) expression:

```
x = y < 0 ? -y : y;
```

Comment: I just wondered if there was a more effective way to do it. However your example taught me something new, thanks. :)